# Laravel custom component parameter parsing issue

Tags: php, laravel, components, parameter-passing

In my Laravel (7.x) application. I am trying to create a component for links:

Component:

```php
<a class="links" href="{{ $route }}" title="{{ $title ?? null }}">
    @isset($icon)
        <i class="{{ $icon }}"></i>
    @endisset

    @isset($caption)
        <span>{{ $caption }}</span>
    @endisset
</a>
```

```php
<x-link icon="{{ $icon }}" route="{{ route("admin.{$route}.create") }}" />
  OR
<x-link icon="{{ $icon }}" route="{{ route("admin." . $route. ".create") }}" />
  OR
<x-link icon="{{ $icon }}" route="{!! route("admin.{$route}.create") !!}" />
  OR
<x-link icon="{{ $icon }}" route="{!! route("admin." . $route. ".create") !!}" />
```

And getting this issue:

```
syntax error, unexpected token "endif", expecting end of file (View: \path)
```

However, if I do this, then it works:

```php
$url = route("admin.{$route}.create");

...

<x-link icon="{{ $icon }}" route="{{ $url }}"></x-link>
```

I am not a fan of declaring the variables just for single use, I like to pass the value directly. Therefore, I prefer the first method.

Why is this simple code not working..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the parameters work better, if the values are bind with them.

```php
<x-link icon="{{ $icon }}" :route="route('admin.' . $route . '.create')" />
```

Additionally... In case, if the multiple values are required:

```php
<x-link icon="{{ $icon }}" :route="route('admin.' . $route . '.create')" :params="[
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => [
        ...
    ],
]" />
```